# onPostExecute() executes before doInBackground() has finished in API 23

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I want to create a radio application which contain a toggleButton, as always a progressBar should be shown until the radio executes.

I'm trying to show a ProgressBar until the doInBackground() has finished. My code works fine in all android versions execpt android api 23 (android marshmallow 6.0), where onPostExecute() executes before doInBackground(). This is my code:

*MainActivity* :

```
    ToggleButton MusicButton;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    String stream = "RADIO_URL";
    boolean prepared = false;
    boolean started = false ;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes attribs = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(attribs);

        }else {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

        /****/
        MusicButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        MusicButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        MusicButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if ( started && MusicButton.isChecked()) {
                    started=false;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    MusicButton.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    started=true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    MusicButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });

 class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {
        ProgressBar radio = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.radioloading);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            radio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared=true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return prepared;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            MusicButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MusicButton.setChecked(true);
            radio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think  onPostExecute is called before doInBackground?

Comment: @greenapps when I run the app the progressBar didn't show, the line radio.setVisibility(View.GONE) execute first !

Comment: I will believe that you do not see the progressbar at all. But i do not believe that setvisiblility gone executes first. You should have better arguments. Why would you see a progress bar? Those three statements in doInBackground are executed so quick that you will not see the bar. Pretty normal. I wonder what you expect about how long doInBackground would 'run'.

Comment: The radio is based on a url, so the progressBar should be shown a while (3-6sec) I tried the application in different androids' versions the progressBar works on all versions except 6.0 it shows the toggleButton directly and the radio isn't played.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the calssic "Use UI thread for update UI components" issue. The visibility of your UI components isn't being changed at all, since you're trying to change the visibility from another thread (the AsyncTask's thread). Please try to use the AsyncTask's `publishProgress(someProgress)` method and hook from the `onProgressUpdate(aListener)` method from the AsyncTask and update the UI visibility there.

Let me know if that doesn't fix the issue.